# Being in "1 Reviewer(s) invited" state for 4 months, What should I do?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I have submitted an article in a math journal, the status has remained at "1 Reviewer(s) invited" for the past 4 months. In an attempt to understand the reasons behind this delay and seek an update, I reached out to the journal's editorial team. Their response was as follows:

*"We have received your submission in good order. It has been assigned to an Editor who has invited reviewers. You are able to follow the status of your manuscript from your author dashboard."*

This response didn't answer my question or provide any assistance.

Is it recommended to wait further for the review process to complete? What are the steps I can take?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a) see "Peer review" section of the answer

Comment: Also see this question
https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/is-my-paper-under-review-or-similar-for-too-long-and-if-yes-how-should-i-reac

Comment: Additional details which may be needed: could you give more details on the subject you are working on/type of paper you submitted/the type of journal.

Comment: @JackRed I am working on Nevanlinna theory (value distribution theory) and have submitted my article to the Mediterranean Journal of Mathematics